# Plane waves in terms of spherical waves in 2D

Tags: waves

We can express plane wave in terms of a spherical waves in 3D as:
\begin{equation}
e^{ikz}=\frac{2\pi i}{k}\delta(\vec{n}-\vec{e}_z)\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}+\frac{2\pi i}{k}\delta(\vec{n}+\vec{e}_z)\frac{e^{-ikr}}{r}
\end{equation}

Where $\vec{n}$: vector in radial direction

and $\vec{e}_z$: basis vector in z direction

I want to know what is it's analogue in 2D ?

Comment: That expression is incorrect. (For a quick look at why, evaluate it along the x or y axes.) Why do you think it holds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 3D Case: your expansion is wrong

The expression you wrote is not right, here is the correct expansion: using spherical coordinates $(r,\theta, \phi)$, there is something called **partial wave decomposition**, and for the wave $e^{i\vec k\cdot\vec r}$ it gives

$$e^{i\vec k\cdot\vec r} =\sum_{l=0}^{+\infty}i^l(2l+1)j_l(kr)P_l(\cos \theta)$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the vertors $\vec k$ (the direction of propagation) and $\vec r$, $P_l(x)$ are the *Legendre polynomials* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials and the $j_l(x)$ are the *modified Bessel functions of the first kind* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions.

In the particular case of a wave propagating in the $z$ direction, i.e $\theta=0$, $\cos\theta=1$, the decomposition semplifies because $P_l(1)=1 \quad\forall l$.

The most interesting aspect though, is that these Bessel functions are oscillating functions with a decreasing amplitude, and for large $r=|\vec r|$ it can be shown that is valid the approximation

$$j_l(kr)\approx \dfrac{1}{kr}\sin\left( kr-l\frac{\pi}{2} \right)=
\dfrac{1}{2ikr}\left(e^{ikr}e^{-il\pi/2}-e^{-ikr}e^{il\pi/2}\right)=\\
\dfrac{1}{2ikr}\left((-i)^le^{ikr}-i^le^{-ikr}\right)$$

So, for large $r$ it is clear that we have a decomposition in outgoing and ingoing spherical waves. I don't know your background, but in quantum mechanics each term is the component of a free particle with angular momentum $l$, and this is relevant in scattering theory.

### 2D case

Similarly to the 3D case it can be shown in 2D, using polar coordinates, that it is valid the expansion
$$e^{i\vec k\cdot\vec r}=e^{ikr\cos\theta}=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\epsilon_mi^m\cos(m\theta)J_m(kr)$$
where $\epsilon_0=1$ and $\epsilon_m=2\forall m>0$, where the functions $J_m(x)$ are another kind of Bessel functions (cylindrical Bessel functions) that have a similar approximation for large $r$.